# Adding mapTypeOptions inside map Angular agm

Tags: angular, google-maps-api-3, agm, agm-core

I am new to angular. I want to add google maps inside my angular application. I am using agm module. But I am not able to add mapTypeControlOptions field inside it. When I try to add it inside HTML, the page stops loading but no errors are shown.
`<agm-map id='map' [latitude]=37.4275 [longitude]= -122.1697 [zoom]=16 [mapTypeId]="'roadmap'"[mapTypeControl]="false" [disableDefaultUI]="true" [zoomControl]="false" [streetViewControl]="false" fullscreenControl]="false" [gestureHandling]="greedy" [mapTypeControlOptions]={the options}></agm-map>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually agm core has a bug in their package due to which the mapcontroloptions were not available. I got around to it but moving backwards to 1.0.0 beta 7 but it is only angular 8 compatible, so we had to make a tradeoff.